# UWP Fit zoomable image in its container

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml

To make an image zoomable I'm using wrapping the image control with a `ScrollViewer` like such:

```
<Page ...>
    <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" VerticalScrollMode="Auto">
        <Image Source="http://i.imgur.com/iseJWq1.jpg" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

I want the image to be resized to fit inside the page in both horizontal and vertical directions, just like the `Stretch="Uniform"` behaviour of the `Image` control:

[image]

But instead it resizes the image to fit horizontally only, clipping the excess of the image on the vertical direction:

[image]

I got some head start from [this website](http://igrali.com/2015/07/17/why-is-my-zoomable-scrollviewer-snapping-the-image-to-the-left/), so I changed the xaml to look like:

```
<Page x:Name="Page"
... />
    <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" VerticalScrollMode="Auto">
        <Image Source="http://i.imgur.com/iseJWq1.jpg" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Page}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Page}" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

While this works fine on the stretching side of things, the image then becomes aligned to the left of the screen, and weird things happen when you zoom in/out:

[image]

Playing with the `Stretch` properties of the image have no effect.

How do I then make the image zoomable while initially fitting the image inside its container, just like any photo viewer app would do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
<Page x:Name="Page"     ...>
    <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled" MinZoomFactor="1" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Image Source="http://i.imgur.com/iseJWq1.jpg" MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Page}" MaxHeight="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Page}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

...which is exactly what the article recommended to be done.

Comment: I wish I had paid more attention to the article to begin with.